# In DOcplex, how can I get value of variable for objective function before solved?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, python, nonlinear-programming, docplex, cplex-python-api

In terms of python based atypical math model as shown below, which is unlike nonlinear or quadratic form in my opinion, I have difficulty in accessing value of variable before optimization as following error message, `DOcplexException: Model<docplex_model1> has not been solved yet`. As a matter of fact, my real module represented by `cal_spl()` is much more complex algebraic model using numpy and pandas. The main thing is that output of the module is a term of the objective function and value of the variables in the model is transformed into input of the module.

How can I get value of variable for module as a part of objective function before solved?

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model
import cplex

mdl = Model()

x = mdl.integer_var(lb=0, ub=cplex.infinity, name='var_x')
y = mdl.integer_var(lb=0, ub=cplex.infinity, name='var_y')

mdl.add_constraint(4*x+3*y >=30, 'Constraint')

def cal_spl(x, y, mdl):
    k, l = 1, 1
    for i in range(1, x.solution_value+2):
        for j in range(1, y.solution_value+3):
            k = k*i
            l = l*l
            result = k- l
    return result

mdl.minimize(50*x+40*y-cal_spl(x, y, mdl))

mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v, " =", v.solution_value)
```

Comment: It seems rather reasonable, that cplex cannot tell you the value of a variable before solving the problem! Is there something in the question I missed?

Comment: As Sune mentioned, that's not possible to get the solution value before solving the problem. Without knowing much about your problem, probably what you want to do is to replace `cal_spl` term in your objective function with a new variable, and then, express the relation you try to establish in `cal_spl` function, through writing constraints between that new variable and `x` and `y`

Comment: Thank you @Sue. Previously, I issued similar problem about Gurobi : [link](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4416886974609-How-can-I-get-values-of-variables-awaiting-model-update-in-Gurobi-python).
I found Gurobi provides update method to make variable's properties accessible before optimization but I couldn't access the 'value' of a variable before solving and in order to mix my atypical math model and optimization solver, it seems like that I have to modify the whole math model for the solver library applicable, which is indeed hardly thinkable for me.

Comment: Thank you @Ehsank as well. Since then, I considered another solver such as SCIP which, I thought, would provide (even pseudo) value function because they are open source. Unfortunately they delivered limited work than I wanted and CPLEX looks similar as Gurobi case.

Comment: As of now, I guess the nature of an objective function could matter whether they are possible to investigate convexity, relaxation applicable to search algorithm like interior point, branch&bound, gradient descent etc. and am supposed to study mathematical programming itself rather than solver usage.